# How to start a session using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a simple page where when a submit button is clicked, it checks if the user exists in the database. If so, it should log that use in and start a session.

The querying of the database works just fine, but a session doesn't start. This is what I have tried for now:

```js
$(".btnSub").click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  var str = $('#inviteCode').val();
  if (str.length == 0 || str.length < 4) {
    swal({
      title: "Invitation Code Error",
      text: "Your invitation code should be 5 characters long. Please try again or go straight to the wedding site",
      type: "warning",
    });
    return;
  } else {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    //var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        if (this.responseText.includes("exist")) {
          swal({
            title: "Invitation Code Error",
            text: this.responseText,
            type: "warning",
          });
        } else {
          $("#wedBtn").show();
          swal("Thanks!", this.response, "success");
        }
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "getData.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
});
```

in my php (getData.php), I have the following:

```
    <?php 
    require 'dbh.php';
    $q = $_REQUEST["q"];
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['login_user']=$q;
    $updateQuery = "UPDATE `Guest` SET `Confirmed`='1' WHERE `InviteCode`= '$q' AND `Confirmed` = '0'";
    $selectQuery2 = "SELECT `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Confirmed`, `InviteCode`, `PlusOnes` FROM `Guest` WHERE `InviteCode` = '$q'";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($updateQuery);
    $stmt->execute();
    $selectStmt = $conn->prepare($selectQuery2);
    $selectStmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        if ($selectStmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            $row = $selectStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_LAST);
            $hint = "Thank you for your response " . $row[0]. ". We are happy to confirm your attendance to the wedding with " .$row[4] . " guests. Please proceed to the wedding site";
            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $q;
            $selectStmt = null;
        }
    }elseif($selectStmt->rowCount() > 0 && $stmt->rowCount() == 0){
        $row = $selectStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_LAST);
        $hint = "Thank you " . $row[0]. ". You have already previously responded. We are happy to confirm your attendance to the wedding with ". $row[4] . " guests. If that decision has changed,
           please contact the organiser on the number provided on your invitation card or proceed to the wedding site.";
        $selectStmt = null;
    }else{
        $hint = 'The invitation code you entered does not exist. Please try again.';
    }
    $conn = null;
//  if(session_start()) echo "session started";
    echo $hint;
?>
```

Also, i want user to be able to access the next page only if they a session has been successfully created.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP. Never insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. You're using prepared statements but not parameterisation, this is not enough on its own.

Comment: Also why do you write `$_SESSION['login_user']=$q;` _before_ you've verified the user? That seems to defeat the point.

Comment: And I think `$row = $selectStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_LAST);
        do{
          $hint = "Thank you for your response " . $row[0]. ". We are happy to confirm your attendance to the wedding with " .$row[4] . " guests. Please proceed to the wedding site";
          $_SESSION['login_user'] = $q;
        } while($row = $selectStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM, PDO::FETCH_ORI_PRIOR));` is wrong. You're expecting one row, right? You already fetched it as $row. Check that exists and is what you expect, and set the session accordingly.I think your loop probably never runs (no more rows)

Comment: I see you're using JQuery already, why not use ajax()? 
[http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: @ADyson the fetching works just fine. I will work on refarctoring the code later.. my concern for now is the session

Comment: @saint yes that's my point. Both my points were about the session, in fact. The removal of the loop I described is a factor in that, because you try to set the session value within the loop, but I suspect the loop is not executing because there are no more rows after you already fetched the first one via a single statement..

Comment: Could you do `if(session_start()) echo "session started";` to check if the problem is there or in the variable declaration?

Comment: @MarioZ it says session started. but when i now try navigating to the welcome page where I have <?php if (isset($_SESSION['login_user'])): ?>
 <body>... it is meant to display the page since the session started but it does not

Comment: @ADyson i made the changes.. pls see my previous comment

Comment: it works now. figured out. I wasnt starting session in my welcome page